# Mapping DB structure to nHibernate mapping files

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following DB structure, and I need to create the relevant nHibernate Mapping files. The problem I am having is one-one, many-one and bag mappings. My current mapping data is also below, any help is appreciated to figure it out.

[image]

**FABMatrix**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="FABMatrix" table="FABMatrix" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="ProductName"/>
        <bag name="FABData" table="FABMatrix_to_FABMatrixData">
            <key column="FABMatrixId"/>
            <many-to-many class="FABMatrixData" column="FABDataId"/>
        </bag>
        <property name="DateCreated" column="DateCreated"/>
        <property name="DateModified" column="DateModified"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**FABMatrixData**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="FabMatrixData" table="FABMatrixData" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Text" column="Text"/>
        <one-to-one name="Type" class="FABType"></one-to-one>
        <property name="DateCreated" column="DateCreated"/>
        <property name="DateModified" column="DateModified"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**FABType**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="FABType" table="FABTypes" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
        <id name="id" column="ID">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="Name"/>
        <many-to-one name="Data" class="FABMatrixData" column="FABTypeId">
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="DateCreated" column="DateCreated"/>
        <property name="DateModified" column="DateModified"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: I think you got the concepts mixed up. FABMatrixData should have a many-to-one to FABType, not one-to-one. And FABType should have none, or an inverse bag of FABMatrixData, not many-to-one.

Comment: Slightly irrelevant, but why dont you use Fluent NHibernate?  It would be easier to map since it is validated at compile-time. All of the above can be easily mapped using FNH.  If you need help on FNH let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Add an unique ID to FABMatrix_to_FABMatrixData table.
2. Add an ICollection of type FabMatrixData property to FABMatrix, object("FABMatrixDataSet").
3. Initialize your ICollection as a HashedSet in FABMatrix contractor -

   ```
   class FABMatrix
   {        
     public virtual ICollection<FabMatrixData> FABMatrixDataSet { get; set;}
     public FABMatrix()
     {
        FABMatrixDataSet = new HashedSet<FabMatrixData>();
     }
   }
   ```
4. Map it with Set mapping -

   ```
   <set name="FABMatrixDataSet" table="FABMatrix_to_FABMatrixData" cascade="none">
       <key column="FABMatrixId"/>
       <many-to-many class="FABMatrixData" column="FABDataId"/>
   </set>
   ```